# Using "infinitive" or "gerund" in subordinate clause

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitives, gerunds

For example

> The main idea is **to use** some features to judge each node whether it is a text node or not.

vs.

> The main idea is **using** some features to judge each node whether it is a text node or not.

Is there difference among them? are they both grammatical?

Comment: The first one is more common. However, I think it will sound more natural if it is as the following: " The main idea of using some features is to judge each node whether it is a text node or not."

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical. The infinitive is somewhat more common, but the gerund avoids the awkward repetition of infinitives.

In either case, the end of the sentence needs to be rewritten:

> ... to judge whether each node is a text node or not.